# A Dictionary where its value is an Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, dictionary

How to design this kind of class implementation in Java? In a way:

```
<K, V[]>
```

Say we have a drug database and we want to add all of its corresponding side effects into its V[], where V[] is a list of side effects (may be a list of strings)?

I have tried `<K, V[]>`, but it didn't work. Probably my implementation was faulty. I am not sure how to design such data structure. Please help, thanks.

---

First attempt:

I have initialized a small piece of code:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class DrugDatabse
{
    private Drug[] listOfDrugs;
    private class Drug<K, List<V>> implements Map, Serializable
    {
        private Map<K, List<V>> dictionary = new Map<K, List<V>>();
        private List<V> sideEffects = new List<V>();

        private Drug(K name, V sideEffects)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Looks like it's not a good start.

---

Second attempt:

DrugDatabase.java:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class DrugDatabase
{
    private Map<Drug, List<SideEffect>> map = new HashMap<Drug, 
            List<SideEffect>>();

    public DrugDatabase(Drug name, SideEffect se)
    {
        map.put(name, se);
    }

    public SideEffect add(Drug name, SideEffect se)
    {
        map.get(name).add(se);
    }

    public List<SideEffect> getSideEffects(Drug name)
    {
        return map.get(name);
    }
}
```

Drug.java:

```
public class Drug
{
    private String name;
    public Drug(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

SideEffect.java:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SideEffect
{
    private List<String> se = new ArrayList<String>();

    public SideEffect(String content)
    {
        se.add(content);
    }
}
```

Comment: You want a `Map<Drug, List<SideEffect>>`. Or a Guava `Multimap<Drug, SideEffect>`. A `Map<Drug, SideEffect[]>` is possible as well, but arrays are fixed-length. How did you test it?

Comment: @JBNizet compiler won't allow V[] in `<K, V[]>`

Comment: Show us real code. V is not a class. `Map<Drug, SideEffect[]>` is a valid declaration (provided Drug and SideEffect are existing classes).

Comment: I have deleted the source code... it didn't work on my implementation (it must have been faulty).

Comment: Next time you ask a question here, post the code you tried. This way we can at least explain what you did wrong.

Comment: Sure. I have started a new piece, is my initial implementation a good start?

Comment: No. not at all. A Drug is not a Map. A Drug is the key of your map, which should be a a field of type Map<Drug, List<SideEffect>> in your DrugDatabase class. You shouldn't try to implement your own map. Each class should be defined in its own file.

Comment: @JBNizet I have posted my second attempt, am I getting there?

Comment: It's closer, but it doesn't even compile because braces are missing. new Map() doesn't make sense, since Map is an interface. You need to instantiate a concrete class which implements the Map interface, like `new HashMap<>()`. You shouldn't name `SideEffects` a class which represent ONE SideEffect. You should name it `SideEffect`.

Comment: Thanks. I have removed ArrayList/List in SideEffects, remain a description of the SideEffect. It's now working.

Answer (score 3):

Either use a:

```
Map<K, List<V>>
```

or use Guava and a:

```
Multimap<K, V>
```

Guava's implementation advantage is that you won't need to worry about non existing keys; whereas with the former, you'll have to create by yourself an empty `List<V>` for each new key.

Another advantage of Guava's Multimap is that you have a `.containsValue()` method which will look over all `List<V>` entries if an element *in any list* exists.

In short, use Guava. [Link to `Multimap` javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v16.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

edit: if you have many side effects common to many drugs, you may also have a look at Guava's Table.

Comment: Could you give me an example of implementation, for example, add a side effect "se1" to drug "Aspirin" on normal java? I am confused of how to use Map

Comment: `List<String> sideEffects = map.get("Aspirin"); sideEffects.add("se1");`

Comment: Or, in a shorter form: `map.get("Aspirin").add("se1");` <-- works since `.get()` returns a `List` which has an `.add()` method. But again, if you have no `"aspirin"` key, you'll have a problem, which `Multimap` solves for you. Note that it presupposes `String` as both keys and values.